# What kind of helper method would I need to find an intersection between two arraylists?! (recursion only)

Tags: java, recursion, arraylist, intersection

So I have the method

```
public ArrayList<String> intersection( ArrayList<String> A1, ArrayList<String> A2)
```

and Im not sure what my helper method would look like to return an ArrayList with elements that are in both A1 and A2, * in the order they occur in A1 *, and * leave A1 and A2 unchanged *

This is what I have written in main to test.

```
ArrayList A1 = new ArrayList();
ArrayList A2 = new ArrayList();
A1.add("a"); A1.add("b"); A1.add("c");
A2.add("b"); A2.add("c"); A2.add("d"); A2.add("e");
ArrayList intersect = Practice.intersection(A1,A2);
System.out.println(A1 + " intersect " + A2 + " = " + intersect);
```

example output I want is
[a, b, c] intersect [b, c, d, e] = [b, c]

Comment: what's you expectation when inputs are `[a,b,c]` and `[c,b,d,e]`?

Comment: expectation output? if that's what you are asking, then same thing [b,c]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want a **recursive** implementation for your `intersection` method. Basically, you want to iterate over `a1` and check for each element, whether it is contained in `a2`.

You can iterate over `a1` using recursion: In each step, you remove the `head` of the list and check whether it is contained in `a2`, and then you `addAll` elements from the intersection of the `tail` with `a2`.

Look at the code: it should be mostly self-explanatory.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<String> a1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> a2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    a1.add("a"); a1.add("b"); a1.add("c");
    a2.add("b"); a2.add("c"); a2.add("d"); a2.add("e");
    ArrayList<String> intersect = intersection(a1, a2);
    System.out.println(a1 + " intersect " + a2 + " = " + intersect);
}

static <A> ArrayList<A> intersection(ArrayList<A> a1, ArrayList<A> a2){
    if(a1.isEmpty())
        return a1;
    else {
        ArrayList<A> result = new ArrayList<A>();
        A head = a1.get(0);
        if (a2.contains(head)) 
            result.add(head);
        ArrayList<A> tail = new ArrayList<>();
        tail.addAll(a1.subList(1, a1.size()));
        result.addAll(intersection(tail, a2));
        return result;
    }
}
```

There is a small pitfall with Java's mutable lists: Note that you could get `head` and `tail` with one simple operation: `a1.remove(0)`. However, if you do not make a defensive copy first, then you will modify your original `a1`, which is definitively not what you want.